# Return the correct item position clicked in RecyclerView to another activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm struggling with this problem for weeks and i always get (1) returned from RecyclerView

- i want to return the right item position clicked to SceneFormeActivity to be able to chose the correct object, but i'm getting the same "1" everytime so the same Case1'Object informations

my main class.kt code :

```
class ListeMeuble3DActivity : AppCompatActivity(),{
    var listMeubles = mutableListOf<Meuble>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_meuble3_d)
         listMeubles = generateList()
        buildRecyclerView()
    }

    private fun generateList(): MutableList<Meuble>{

        val list = ArrayList<Meuble>()

           // to Add an Object Meuble(nom,prix,stock)

            val meuble = Meuble(R.drawable.fauteilgris, "Gris","25000da",1)
            val meuble1 = Meuble(R.drawable.fauteuille1, "","1000d&",1)
            val meuble2 = Meuble(R.drawable.burau, "Bureau","25000da",1)
            list.add(meuble)
            list.add(meuble1)
            list.add(meuble2)

        return list
    }

    fun buildRecyclerView() {
        mon_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
        //mon_recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter)
        mon_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        mon_recycler.adapter = MeubleAdapter(listMeubles.toTypedArray())
        {
            val intent3 = Intent(this, SceneformeActivity::class.java)
            intent3.putExtra("image_url",1)
            startActivity(intent3)
        }
     }
 }
```

My Adapter Class .kt:

```
class MeubleAdapter(private val exampleList: Array<Meuble>,val listener: (Meuble)-> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MeubleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.meuble_item,
            parent, false)
        return ExampleViewHolder(itemView)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = exampleList[position]
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.imageResource)
        holder.textViewNomMeuble.text = currentItem.nom
        holder.textViewPrix.text = currentItem.prix
        holder.textViewStock.text = currentItem.stock.toString()

        holder.bind(exampleList[position],listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = exampleList.size


    class ExampleViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(meuble:Meuble,listener: (Meuble) -> Unit)= with(itemView)
        {
            android.util.Log.i("XXXX","FCT Bind ")
            setOnClickListener{(listener(meuble))}
        }

        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.image_view
        val textViewNomMeuble: TextView = itemView.nomMeuble
        val textViewStock: TextView = itemView.stock
        val textViewPrix: TextView = itemView.prix

    }
}
```

My function in SceneFormeActivity.java where im supposed to get the item position

```
private void initializeGallery() {
        int imageUrl = getIntent().getIntExtra("image_url",0); // here, everytime it return 1
        LinearLayout gallery = findViewById(R.id.gallery_layout);
        int obj =imageUrl;
        switch (obj) {
            case 0: {
                ImageView andy = new ImageView(this);
                andy.setImageResource(R.drawable.fauteilgris);
                andy.setContentDescription("fauteuil Créme");
                andy.setOnClickListener(view ->{addObject(Uri.parse("foteuil.sfb"));});
                gallery.addView(andy);

            }
            break;
            case 1: {
                ImageView andy = new ImageView(this);
                andy.setImageResource(R.drawable.banc);
                andy.setContentDescription("banc extérieur");
                andy.setOnClickListener(view ->{addObject(Uri.parse("Bench.sfb"));});
                gallery.addView(andy);

            }
            break;
            case 2 : {
                ImageView andy = new ImageView(this);
                andy.setImageResource(R.drawable.burau);
                andy.setContentDescription("bureau");
                andy.setOnClickListener(view ->{addObject(Uri.parse("bureau.sfb"));});
                gallery.addView(andy);

            }
            break;
            case 3 : {
                ImageView andy = new ImageView(this);
                andy.setImageResource(R.drawable.fauteuille3);
                andy.setContentDescription("Fauteuil une place");
                andy.setOnClickListener(view ->{addObject(Uri.parse("ff.sfb"));});
                gallery.addView(andy);

            }
            break;
            default:Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: "always get (1) returned from RecyclerView" because you are passing 1 to an Intent ``intent3.putExtra("image_url",1)`` change 1 to position from ``onBind(..)`` method

Comment: You can put a TextView with visibility GONE and save your ids the RecyclerView, after this its more easy handle the data of the item with simple check of the id

Comment: @chandmohd this is my problem, i don't know how get the position from bind(..) to buildRecycleView   adapter

Comment: @luisenricke i get ur idea, i'll try it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you really want is the position of the item then you don't need to send the Meuble on click at all.  In your adapter change `onBindViewHolder` to:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = exampleList[position]
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.imageResource)
        holder.textViewNomMeuble.text = currentItem.nom
        holder.textViewPrix.text = currentItem.prix
        holder.textViewStock.text = currentItem.stock.toString()

        holder.bind(position,listener)
    }
```

Setting your adapter should now look like this:

```
 mon_recycler.adapter = MeubleAdapter(listMeubles.toTypedArray()){ position ->
            val intent3 = Intent(this, SceneformeActivity::class.java)
            intent3.putExtra("image_url", position)
            startActivity(intent3)
        }
```

---

Edit: Expanding on the adapter usage:

Originally, you are passing two things to your Recyclerview Adapter -

1. The list of Meuble (There is no need to convert this to a TypedArray
2. The lambda that will act on the click of an item in the list

Consider the refactored code below with my inline comments.  Note - it's not clear to me why you are sending position (assuming just to test?) So instead I'm assuming there is some imageURL in the object that you wish to send.  I show below how you'd access that.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_meuble3_d)
    listMeubles = generateList()
    buildRecyclerView()
}

private fun generateList(): MutableList<Meuble>{

    val list = mutableListOf<Meuble>()

       // to Add an Object Meuble(nom,prix,stock)

        val meuble = Meuble(R.drawable.fauteilgris, "Gris","25000da",1)
        val meuble1 = Meuble(R.drawable.fauteuille1, "","1000d&",1)
        val meuble2 = Meuble(R.drawable.burau, "Bureau","25000da",1)
        list.add(meuble)
        list.add(meuble1)
        list.add(meuble2)

    return list
}

fun buildRecyclerView() {
    mon_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    mon_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    // NOTE: Here the lambda implicitly had an item of type Meuble passed.  We name it here but could have just used "it".
    mon_recycler.adapter = MeubleAdapter(listMeubles.toTypedArray())
    { item ->
        val intent3 = Intent(this, SceneformeActivity::class.java)
        intent3.putExtra("image_url",item.imageUrl)
        startActivity(intent3)
    }
 }
```

}
My Adapter Class .kt:

```
// Don't need to pass as a TypedArray - List is fine
class MeubleAdapter(private val exampleList: List<Meuble>,val listener: (Meuble)-> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MeubleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.meuble_item,
            parent, false)
        return ExampleViewHolder(itemView)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = exampleList[position]
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.imageResource)
        holder.textViewNomMeuble.text = currentItem.nom
        holder.textViewPrix.text = currentItem.prix
        holder.textViewStock.text = currentItem.stock.toString()

        holder.bind(exampleList[position],listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = exampleList.size


    class ExampleViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(meuble:Meuble,listener: (Meuble) -> Unit)= with(itemView)
        {
            android.util.Log.i("XXXX","FCT Bind ")
            setOnClickListener{(listener(meuble))}
        }

        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.image_view
        val textViewNomMeuble: TextView = itemView.nomMeuble
        val textViewStock: TextView = itemView.stock
        val textViewPrix: TextView = itemView.prix

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply 
i can't just pass position in holder.bind,, however i tried to change the function bind to take just Int Position parameter, and i had a problem to call it because position -> return un object not int , 
so i think my problem is that i don't know how to get the data passed here         holder.bind(exampleList[position],listener)

```
mon_recycler.adapter = MeubleAdapter(listMeubles.toTypedArray())
        {
            val intent3 = Intent(this, SceneformeActivity::class.java)
            intent3.putExtra("image_url",1) // to replace 1 

 }
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that you don't understand how to deal with the object that is passed to your lambda?

Comment: u actually helped me to understand more the topic, thank you, 
however i want the position of the item clicked to send it to my next Activity and chose the correct 3D object to show 3D
but everytime in putExtra i get only my 4 properties passed in onBindViewHolder (imageResource, prix, name, Stock), i don't know maybe my first think wouldn't work even if i get the position,,   so i used the name of the object clicked and compare(switch case(name))  with the name of the object and it work 

thank you for helping me to understand more the adapter work

Answer (score 0):

So i used this solution,, i passed the name (nom) of my clicked object to the SceneFormActivity to get the reference and display my 3D object in the next activity:

code from main

```
   val intent3 = Intent(this, SceneformeActivity::class.java)
            intent3.putExtra("image_url",it.nom) //  it.nom to get the name of the object clicked
            startActivity(intent3)
```

and in SceneformeActivity :

```
 private void initializeGallery() {
        String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url"); // changed this from getInt to getString to get the name
        LinearLayout gallery = findViewById(R.id.gallery_layout);
        String obj =imageUrl;   
        switch (obj) {
            case "fauteilgris": { // case "String": the name of the object clicked in the previous activity(RecyclerView)
                ImageView andy = new ImageView(this);
                andy.setImageResource(R.drawable.fauteilgris);
                andy.setContentDescription("fauteuil Créme");
                andy.setOnClickListener(view ->{addObject(Uri.parse("foteuil.sfb"));});
                gallery.addView(andy);

            }
            break;
            case "banc": {
                ImageView andy = new ImageView(this);
                andy.setImageResource(R.drawable.banc);
                andy.setContentDescription("banc extérieur");
                andy.setOnClickListener(view ->{addObject(Uri.parse("Bench.sfb"));});
                gallery.addView(andy);

            }
            break;
            case "burau": {
                ImageView andy = new ImageView(this);
                andy.setImageResource(R.drawable.burau);
                andy.setContentDescription("bureau");
                andy.setOnClickListener(view ->{addObject(Uri.parse("bureau.sfb"));});
                gallery.addView(andy);

            }
            break;
 default:Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Object",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

        }
    }
```